# Pandas read one parameter from nested json

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, nested

i have a following json file and i would like to read all the parameters: "dataRecordId" only and store them into a df:

```
{'responseInformation': '20 metadata records in response.',
 'metaDataResponse': [{'timestampFrom': '2020-10-07T10:19:07.7810000Z',
   'timestampTo': '2020-10-07T23:59:59.9999990Z',
   'component': {'type': '', 'id': '', 'name': '', 'comment': ''},
   'resource': {'type': 'EQU', 'id': '6100380', 'name': '', 'comment': ''},
   'processStep': {'type': '', 'id': '', 'name': '', 'comment': ''},
   'context': '',
   'dataRecords': [{'dataRecordId': '171533103',
     'groupName': 'Process',
     'sensorName': 'AutomaticProcessActive',
     'profile': 'sd',
     'type': 'Switch2Way',
     'unit': 'state',
     'returnType': 'timeSeries'}]},
  {'timestampFrom': '2020-10-08T00:00:00.6540000Z',
   'timestampTo': '2020-10-08T23:59:59.9999990Z',
   'component': {'type': '', 'id': '', 'name': '', 'comment': ''},
   'resource': {'type': 'EQU', 'id': '6100380', 'name': '', 'comment': ''},
   'processStep': {'type': '', 'id': '', 'name': '', 'comment': ''},
   'context': '',
   'dataRecords': [{'dataRecordId': '171534669',
     'groupName': 'Process',
     'sensorName': 'AutomaticProcessActive',
     'profile': 'sd',
     'type': 'Switch2Way',
     'unit': 'state',
     'returnType': 'timeSeries'}]},
```

This is what i did so far, but i have no idea how to go deeper in the structure, in order to achieve the 'dataRecordId':

```
import json

with open('file_200826_201026.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

    for p in data['metaDataResponse']:
        print('p['dataRecords'])
```

Comment: The `DataRecords` key contains a list. Change your last line to `print(p[0]['dataRecords'])`

Comment: I have got: KeyError: 0

Comment: Does this work: `print(p['dataRecords'][0]['dataRecordId'])`

Comment: Yes, i give the first 3 values (from 20) of 'dataRecordId' and then the error message: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Ok, I see. We have to loop over the data records as well:

`for p in data['metaDataResponse']: 

for r in p['dataRecords']: 

print(r['dataRecordId')`

Comment: Dear Rik, thank you so much. It works like it should be.